# 'my eldest son'

Tags: word-choice, kinship-terms

If there are three children in the family:

A. a boy, eldest

B. a girl

C. a boy, youngest

Is it correct for their father to refer to A as 'my eldest son' and to B as 'my younger daughter'? If not, what expression would be preferred?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you compare two people you should use only the comparative form of the adjective (in your case ‘my ***elder*** son’).

The alternative form can be ‘my eldest child’ as you compare three people here. This is the superlative form of the adjective.

As for the daughter, you just say ‘my daughter’.

Answer (score 1):

You have two sons so it's better to say "my **elder** son". If you have three sons, however, you would say "my **eldest** son" because if you say "my elder son", people will assume you have two sons and not three.

As you only have one daughter, it would be wrong if you said "my younger daughter" (as you don't have a daughter that is older than her). You should simply say "my daughter".